# What is the rigorous interpretation of $y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We obtain $y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$ by solving for $y$ in $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. How exactly do we analyze this statement to determine whether $y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$ implies $y = \sqrt{1-x^2} \lor y = -\sqrt{1-x^2}$ or whether it implies instead $y = \sqrt{1-x^2} \land y = -\sqrt{1-x^2}$? Or is it by definition one or the other? Is there actually a more set-theoretic interpretation of the statement? The idea is to understand why $y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$ could or not produce the graph of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, or to understand how we can properly graph $y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Any help, tips or references are highly appreciated!

Comment: $\pm$ is literally read "plus _or_ minus".  Besides, how would you expect $y$, a single variable, to take on two different values at the same time?

Comment: @shintuku $y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$ is just shorthand for $y \in \{\sqrt{1-x^2}, -\sqrt{1-x^2}\}$.

Comment: @AndrewChin I'm trying to work out how the graph of $y = \pm{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ works. If it is $\land$, it seems to me to contradict the definition of a function, but not if it is $\lor$

Comment: @dxiv thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @shintuku Circles aren't functions

Comment: @TheBestMagician right, I'm trying to understand how to prove this in the above mentioned case, by finding the proper statement when we use $\pm$

Comment: $y=\pm z$ is just shorthand for "$y=z$ or $y=-z.$" Therre isn't a real notion of which one is true. If you know the sign of $y$ and $z,$ you can figure it out.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you very much!

Comment: @shintuku There is an easier way to prove it... Just take $x=0$ and we get two values for $y$.